# Neumann boundary condition in 4D for Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Is there any explicit form for the Neumann boundary condition $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \hat n}\rvert_{\partial\Omega}=0$

for the Laplace equation in 4D for $u=u(x,y,z,w) $:

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}+u_{ww}=0$

In other words, what is $\nabla u \cdot \hat n$ in this case?

Comment: The dot product of two vectors works in any dimension.

Comment: @KurtG. of course, but what is the definition of $\hat n$ ? as function of $u$, $\nabla u$ etc.

Comment: $\hat{n}$ is the vector that is normal to the boundary of the region. Looks like you denote that boundary by $\Omega$. What dimension must $\Omega$ have such that at each of its points there is exactly one normal vector ?

Comment: @KurtG Sorry, I meant $\partial \Omega$. Corrected it. In my case $\Omega \in {\Bbb R^4}$ so $\partial \Omega \in {\Bbb R^3}$

Comment: The notation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \boldsymbol n}$ is just a notational shorthand for $\boldsymbol n\cdot \nabla u$. They are the same thing.

Comment: As for an explicit form, it will really depend on your domain $\Omega$. In fact for a lot of choices of $\Omega$ a solution may not even exist.

Comment: @K.defaoite there is no general form for $\hat n$ in this case? something like $\hat n=(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},1)$ in the 2D case?

Comment: @BennyK No, there isn't.